# Would a laptop be up to the task of running a server?

Tags: computer-building

I'm looking to upgrade my main Windows tower to a more mobile solution, but the problem is I run highly CPU intensive server and development software on it. The processes can some times run for days on end to finish a task. I tried this on an HP laptop a few years back and it ruined it after only a year due to overheating.

Would any laptops on the market today be up to this task? If so, what sort of specs should I look for?

If not, would a mini ITX work just as well as a full sized motherboard?

Comment: A computer is a computer, form factor in this case is irrelevant.  It might be easier to keep a desktop/ITX computer cool, but certainly you can throttle the CPU in your laptop so it doesn't overheat...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use the Alienware range of laptops for CPU intensive applications and have never had any serious problems that could not be fixed by cleaning the dust out of the fans (office/domestic environment, so dust is plentiful).  I'd suggest whatever you buy, get a good warranty - 3 years is common on the Dell/Alienware range and I don't believe there's any 'acceptable usage' restrictions on how hard/often you drive the cpu.